# SQL overlapping dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

Here, we have many meetings during the day. Usually from 9:00am-11:30am, 1:00pm-3:30pm, 4:00pm-6:30pm.

I'm having a hard time scheduling these meetings. I don't get how to check if they overlap for the same person who is leading the meeting.

Ex:
Should raise an error if Person1 has a meeting scheduled for 10:00am- 11:00am and another for 10:45am-11:30am.

I've come to this solution, but it is only partially working:

```
if exists (
    select 1
    from
        Meeting M
    where
        M.IdPerson = @IdPerson --Stored procedure parameter
        and 
            (@StartDate <= M.EndDate or  -- 1
            @EndDate >= M.StartDate or  -- 2
            (@StartDate > M.StartDate and @DtFim < A.Data_Termino))) -- 3
    return 1
```

In the image below, I explain the three conditions in the where clause. The green lines are the new meeting start and end dates. The red lines are the old's.

[image]

How can I make this work?

Comment: How about some ddl and sample data? sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start.

Comment: You may be interested in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12043793/533120).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the logic you want is:

```
if exists (select 1
           from Meeting M
           where M.IdPerson = @IdPerson and --Stored procedure parameter
                 @StartDate <= M.EndDate and
                 @EndDate >= M.StartDate
          )
    return 1
```

(I'm not sure if you want <= or < for these comparisons.)  This assumes that `StartDate` and `EndDate` also store the time component.

Two time periods overlaps if the first starts before the second ends, and it ends after the second starts.

Comment: The general logic is correct.  However, if both date and time are involved, then the range should be stored as a half-open interval `[start,end)`.  Since both comparisons involve an end value in a range-overlap query, then *neither* should test for equality.  Use `<` and `>`.

Comment: Also note that if these were date-only ranges, then fully-closed intervals would be more appropriate and you would use `<=` and `>=`.

Comment: @MattJohnson . . . The OP suggests that the date/time are actually discreet values at half hour intervals.  What I don't know is whether or not 9:00 a.m. - 10:00 a.m. overlaps with 10:00 a.m. - 10:30 a.m.  Your points about inequalities and date/times are certainly true, though.

Comment: I suppose it's possible that someone might want those to overlap, but in the vast majority of cases I've seen, those would be adjacent and non-overlapping.  Especially for meeting times. That's why I recommend the half-open interval.  Cheers!