# How to make trigger to check that time that user choose it is empty or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Check_time] on [dbo].[Schedule] after insert
AS 

if exists ((select * from Schedule as S Join inserted as i on S.DDate=i.DDate AND S.ST_TIME=i.ST_TIME AND S.END_TIME=i.END_TIME))
BEGIN 
print('INVALID TIME')
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
return
END
```

[image]

*but there is another problem that the user can insert time before the end time for the previous user has been ended , how can i solve it?***

Comment: Why a trigger? Just declare `DDate, ST_TIME, END_TIME` UNIQUE.

Comment: _"...check that time that user choose it is empty or not?"_ Isn't the same as _"Check if exists or not"_. So what are you trying to do really?

Comment: Wouldn't a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` be better?

Comment: Also, how can a `date` be "empty"?

Comment: @Sami i want to make schedule for an advertising screen to make user choose the time he wants to view his content but must check that this time is available not taken by another user

Comment: Then I think you're after `IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE WHERE ...) --Do the job` @MinaEssam

Comment: @MinaEssam My hypothesis is that `DDate, ST_TIME, END_TIME` must be `UNIQUE` excluding cases when those dates are NULL. Maybe that's the reason why CHECK CONSTRAINT is not used? Please clarify

Comment: @AlexYu in another day the time can be repeated , so I think that the unique CHECK CONSTRAINT not be useful

Comment: @MinaEssam "in another day the time can be repeated" -  UNIQUE constraint for combination of fields not for individual fields.  E.g. `CONSTRAINT UI_DDATE_ST_TIME_END_TIME UNIQUE (DDATE, ST_TIME, END_TIME)`. Take a look on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/786cd/1

Comment: @AlexYu its ok ,but there is another problem that the user can insert time before the end time for the previous user has been ended , how can i solve it?

Comment: @MinaEssam "user can insert time before the end time for the previous user has been ended"  - does it means that time periods DDATE-ST_TIME-END_TIME from different rows must not intersect? E.g. it's impossible to have 01:00-05:00 and 02:00-03:00 in the same day? Explain and add to text of your  question consisnency rules you need.

Comment: @AlexYu yes i mean this

Comment: @AlexYu Can you help me to make it ?

Comment: @MinaEssam I hope I understood you correctly (or somewhere near to needed). Look at my answer, check this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035747/date-range-overlapping-check-constraint  -  I used part of this answer. Hope this helps

Comment: @AlexYu i don't understand it and whats meant by 0 and 1

Comment: @MinaEssam Actually it's `false`/`true` but that does not matter, it could any datatype. Constraint defined as: a) function that returns 0(false) in case when no overlaps exists and 1(true) - otherwise, b) CONSTRAINT itself thru application of this function.  Every DML (INSERT/UPDATE) is checked, in case result is 0 (no overlaps) - row inserted/updated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you used Trigger I will answer in Trigger format.
Use INSTEAD OF instead of after insert. In this case, you check the table before setting a record.
Use 2 as a suggestion

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Check_time]
   ON  [dbo].[Schedule]
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Count INT = 0
    SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) 
    FROM Schedule AS S 
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON S.DDate=i.DDate AND S.ST_TIME=i.ST_TIME AND S.END_TIME=i.END_TIME

    IF ISNULL(@Count , 0) = 0
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Schedule] ([MID], [SID], [ST_TIME], [END_TIME], [DDate], [ST_ID])
        select [MID], [SID], [ST_TIME], [END_TIME], [DDate], [ST_ID] FROM inserted
    END 

END
```

Comment: can you type a trigger and send it to me

Comment: or check this url for create index and set IGNORE_DUP_KEY = on :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I wrote TRIGGER .Please check

Comment: my gmail is RezaYousefi88 at gmail dot com. install anydesk  and then i remote to your computer and check togather

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger is just checking for duplicated values.  You are better off with a `unique` constraint:

```
alter table Schedule add constraint unq_schedule_ddate_st_time_end_time
    unique (ddate, st_time, end_time);
```

Comment: but time should be repeats in another day

Comment: @MinaEssam . . . So?  This only eliminates duplicates when all three values are the same, which is what your pseudo-code does.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Problem clarification

After clarifications by OP in comments  it become clear that the main goal is checking overlapping time periods.

E.g.

- combination of periods (`01:00:00`-`02:00:00`, `02:01:00-03:00:00`) - is allowed in the same day
- (`01:00:00`-`05:00:00`,  `02:01:00-03:00:00`) or  (`01:00:00`-`03:00:00`, `02:00:00-04:00:00`) - are disallowed

(I hope that I understood correctly)

Checking for overlapping periods is typical task and I even found existing answer on SO: [Date range overlapping check constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035747/date-range-overlapping-check-constraint)

### 2. Proposed solution

With a little modification I can propose this solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e2146/2

```sql
CREATE TABLE Schedule (
  ID BIGINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  DDate date,
  ST_TIME time,
  END_TIME time
);

-- UNIQUE CONSTRAINT
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UI_DDATE_ST_TIME_END_TIME ON Schedule(DDATE, ST_TIME, END_TIME);

-- CONSTRAINT FOR OVERLAPPING PERIODS
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_chkOverlapping]
(
  @DDate AS DATE,
  @ST_TIME AS TIME,
  @END_TIME time
)
RETURNS BIT
AS 
BEGIN
 RETURN (
  SELECT 
  CASE
     WHEN @ST_TIME>@END_TIME THEN 0
     WHEN EXISTS(
          SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Schedule]
            WHERE
                @DDATE = DDATE
                AND @END_TIME >= ST_TIME
                AND END_TIME >= @ST_TIME
     ) THEN 0
     ELSE 1
  END
 )
END;

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Schedule]  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_Overlapping] CHECK  ([dbo].[fn_chkOverlapping]([DDate],[ST_TIME],[END_TIME])=0);
```

### 3. Alternatives

It's absolutely possible to do this using triggers.

I myself prefer to define constraints by `CREATE CONSTRAINT` than other object types.

It's a question of taste not of necessity.

Comment: but i didn't work the data is wrong data is entered

Comment: @MinaEssam Because you did not defined what is wrong and what is correct. This information is known to only you. Modify INSERT statement with correct data in   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e2146/2  and then modify check function accordingly. What is exactly wrong?